# Can we use different linux distro in Laravel Homestead

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I am wondering If we can use a different distro in Laravel Homestead. Right now it is preconfigured to use an Ubuntu Distro. Can we use other distro like fedora, arch etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No because it's not a simple matter.

Long Answer: I'm working on it, it's just slow going. In my day job I've always used RHEL or CentOS so I've always wanted a CentOS flavored version of Homestead. That's exactly what I've started building with [EnterpriseHomestead](https://github.com/svpernova09/enterprisehomestead) and [EnterpriseSettler](https://github.com/svpernova09/enterprisesettler) projects. It's not quite ready for a alpha, but it is close (despite I haven't had much time to work on it lately, Homestead and support keeps my OSS time pretty tied up)

If you'd like to help out please jump into the repo and start testing / asking questions. I also have #enterprisehomestead on the Freenode IRC network.